# program to remove cheapest item and display highest to lowest

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, decimal

I am working on a program that will ask for 5 items and the price of each - I have created two lists and am required to sort these in order of most expensive.  I need to then show the total of the items, remove the cheapest (discount) and then show the new amount.

I cant get the total to show only 2 decimal places.  very new to this and would appreciate any help.

the code I have so far

```
#Program to work out total bill applying a discount
#create empty list
item = []
price = []

#How many items does the customer have
n = int(input("How many items does the customer have? "))
#input item and price
for i in range(n):
    item.append(input("Please enter item description: "))
    price.append(float(input("Please enter the price £")))

#print(item, price)

#sort list
for x in range(len(price)):
    for y in range(len(price)-1):
        if price[y] > price[+1]:
           item[y], item[y+1] = item[y+1], item[y]
           price[y], price[y+1] = price[y+1], price[y]
#display items

for x in range(len(price)):
    print(item[x], price[x])

#calculate discounts
print("Total bill = ", sum(price))
#del min(price): cant get this removed 
print("Total after discount = ", sum(price))
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add some formatting in your print statements.

for example:

```py
print("Total bill = %.2f" % sum(price))
print("Total after discount = %.2f" % sum(price))
```

The `%.2f` is an instruction to format a `float` with only 2 integers following the decimal point

An alternative that does the exact same thing would be to use an `f-string`.

```
print(f"Total bill = {sum(price):.2f}")
print(f"Total after discount = {sum(price):.2f}")
```

Comment: The modulo print statements have long been ‘outdated’.  Perhaps revise the answer to use f-strings.